# What would be the cardinality of Employee and Department?

Tags: entity, relational-database, entity-relationship

> A company database needs to store information about employees
>   (identified by ssn, with salary and phone as attributes),
>
> departments (identified by dno, with dname and budget as attributes),
>   and children of employees (with name and age as attributes).
>
> Employees work in departments; each department is managed by an
>   employee;
>
> a child must be identified uniquely by name when the parent (who is an
>   employee; assume that only one parent works for the company) is known.
>
> We are not interested in information about a child once the parent
>   leaves the company.
>
> Draw an ER diagram that captures this information.

[image]

I am using "Look Across" Min-Max notation here.

Are the cardinalities between Employee and Department correct?

For instance, is it possible that a Department has zero Employees? Or, is this a relevant information?

Comment: Which textbook is this from? Elmasri & Navathe? Sommerville? The example looks familiar. I might still have instructor copy and can just look up the "correct" answer for ya.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary, I actually don't know the book. It was given in the Tutorials. But, our instructor follows the Navathe-Elmasri book.

Comment: It's the bread-and-butter example used in many courses and texts. As a former CS instructor I would give you full credit; you clearly demonstrated your correct understanding based on the narrative.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary, thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct and matches the instructor key for this common example in two different texts that I own.

*Other thoughts*

Unfortunately most textbooks are poor reflections of reality because they trivialize things, but this is considered necessary when introducing students to complex topics such as modeling reality in a database.

This illustrates problem with creating ERD from English-language narrative which can be ambiguous and open to interpretation, however. Might score some extra points with your instructor if you point that out. In reality, it is not uncommon for employees to work for multiple departments (I do), and for managers to manage multiple departments (mine does). When working with clients it is a good idea to also express the more ambiguous designs with a physical data model (tables and rows) or an actual user interface (form for data entry) so that they are certain of what they are getting.

Answer (score 0):

If a department MUST have a manager and that manager is by relationship working for that department then a department must have minimum 1 employee.

An Employee can (I'm assuming) manage more than 1 department theoretically and a department can also (assumption) be managed by more than 1 Employee.

So I see it like this

```
Employee *-* Department   (many to many relationship)
```

or in your terms

```
Employee  1-N  Works In    1-N  Department
Employee  1-N  Managed By  1-N  Department
```

Comment: Why assume? This is obviously trivial textbook example. Does not matter what reality is. Re read the narrative. Department is managed by *an* (one) employee. But employees work for departments begs clarification since ambiguous but I read it as employees can work in multiple departments and can also manage multiple.

Comment: Yeah - I get it.. but in real world situation it is best practice to go back to client to clarify, not build what you *assume* they meant.

Comment: Of course, but given said client is not paying me for my time I'll give the best answer to the best assumption I can make given the vague question provided

Answer (score 0):

You cardinality is incorrect for the case employee works in department. Since an employee can work in 0 or many departments. Here, the cardinality should be as follows:

employee (0,n)  - works in (0,n) departments.

While in the other case department has to have an employee associated with it.
The cardinality in the case department managed by employee is correct in your case.